# POSIX timer : Invalid argument

Tags: c++, timer, segmentation-fault, posix

I'm trying to use a POSIX timer, but my code can't run.

```
timer_t id_timer_;

// some code. timer_create(), etc.

void timerPeriod (unsigned long sec, unsigned long nsec)
{
  struct itimerspec myperiod;
  myperiod.it_interval.tv_sec = sec;
  myperiod.it_interval.tv_nsec = nsec;
  myperiod.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
  myperiod.it_value.tv_nsec = nsec;

  if (timer_settime (&id_timer_, 0, &myperiod, 0))
    perror("timer_settime");
}
```

It returns `timer_settime: Invalid argument`, while arguments are looking good to me.

I also tried `timer_settime(id_timer_, 0, &myperiod, 0)` (without the **&** before `id_timer_`), which I think is the good way to use `timer_settime()` : segmentation fault...

Any clue ?

Comment: You need to create the time first using `timer_create`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ordre to create the timer, the `struct sigaction` must be properly set.

```
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sa.sa_sigaction = your_handler;
```

In my previous code, `sa_flags` was set to `0` instead of `SA_SIGINFO`.

More info on [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the precondition for this is that the call to timer_create was successful?

According to the man pages for timer_settime, you can get EINVAL if the timer_id is invalid, or if the itimerspec arguments are < 0 or > 1 million.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_settime

HTH